# onkeylistener don't work on imagebutton

Tags: android, imagebutton, onclicklistener

i have a problem with onkeylistener event, my code is like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pnt_articulo);
    imbAgregarArt = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imbAgregarArt);
    imbAgregarArt.setOnKeyListener(key);
}

OnKeyListener key = new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

i use the debug to stop in Toast line don't enter

Please help

Comment: thanks samir, i was wrong, what i try to do is listen the click button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is listening for key events, meaning keyboard presses and such, and for that purpose your code is perfectly fine. Make sure the `ImageButton` is selected and press any key and your `Toast` will appear.

Since this is a very odd behaviour, you're probably after an `OnClickListener`:

```
....
    imbAgregarArt.setOnClickListener(click);
}

OnClickListener click = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
};
```

Note that we've changed the `OnKeyListener` to an `OnClickListener`, the first one listens to keyboard activity while the second one listens to user interaction with the objects by clicking on them, either with the finger (press) or selecting with a trackpad or whatever the device can do.

As a sido note
If you're curious about why the other one wasn't working even if you pressed a keyboard key, the problem came from the fact that the view wasn't focused. For a view to listen to keyboard events inside of it, they first need to be selected, this sounds logical right?